# Errors when building tensorflow on linux

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build tensorflow on linux Mint 18 64x. I followed the instructions step by step by got this error:

```
ERROR: /home/david/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1489:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:batchtospace_op_gpu':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/core/kernels/batchtospace_op_gpu.cu.cc':
  '/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/cuda_runtime.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/host_config.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/builtin_types.h'
```

The list of header files goes on and on, I just pasted the first 3. Any idea what might be causing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding `cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include"` within `toolchain{}` in the file tensorflow/third_party/gpus/crosstool/CROSSTOOL

However I then got another error:

```
ERROR: /home/david/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1489:1: output 'tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/batchtospace_op_gpu/tensorflow/core/kernels/batchtospace_op_gpu.cu.pic.o' was not created.
```

I was able to solve that one by adding: `cxx_flag: "-D_MWAITXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED"` below each of the two occurrences of `cxx_flag: "-std=c++11"` in the CROSSTOOL file.

I then got yet another error:

```
'depthtospace_op_gpu.cu.o' was not created.
```

which I could solve by adding the following lines below each of the two occurrences of `cxx_flag: "-std=c++11"` in the CROSSTOOL file :

```
  cxx_flag: "-D_FORCE_INLINES"
  cxx_flag: "-D__STRICT_ANSI__"
```

The solutions were found here:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1066
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2143
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1157